# Should git server builds ever not clone to depth of 1?

Tags: git

We've newly switched to git and are working through the nuances.

It seems that on build servers, cloning to a depth of 1 would be the way to always go, since the build server shouldn't need any history.

Is this not a good idea?

Comment: You mention _server builds_ in your title, but not in your question.

Comment: I'm curious, have you found that cloning is time-consuming? If the cloning process is a significant part of your build and/or CI testing, reducing depth seems a good idea. But it would also be good to ask why that is the case. Do you have a very large codebase with extensive history? Or maybe you have too many binary files in git?

Comment: @er Good points... I've adjusted the question to mention server builds. We do have a lot of history and some binaries (holdout from hg that we haven't cleaned up in git, yet). In local testing we found that using a depth of 1 dropped the clone time from 3 minutes to 90 sec, and the size of the repo from 300MB to about half that. (Yes, this is a terrible size for a repo. We'll try to get there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the reason why shallow fetch isn't on by default: ***Sometimes the git server is slower to calculate which commits need to be downloaded than to just serve up full history.***

This is useful to know for, say, researching why git retrieval is taking longer than expected.

From the [VSTS documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository#git):

> Shallow fetch: Select if you want to limit how far back in history to
>   download. Effectively this results in git fetch --depth=n. If your
>   repository is large, this option might make your build process more
>   efficient. Your repository might be large if it has been in use for a
>   long time. It also might be large if you added and later deleted large
>   files.
>
> In these cases this option can help you conserve network and storage
>   resources. It might also save time. The reason it doesn't always save
>   time is because in some situations the server might need to spend time
>   calculating the commits to download.

**Additionally, if the depth value isn't large enough, and the code you're looking for is on a branch or changeset that is not the most recent changeset in the repository, then the needed version will not be pulled down.**

Answer (score 1):

If doing a full clone is too time consuming, cloning at depth of 1 is an option.

You should get a significant increase in speed if you were being delayed by a large history taking a long time to clone before.

If what you are asking is: *is using clone depth 1 fine for a build server?*

Yes, this is fine.

Comment: For others reading this answer, setting depth to 1 can cause unexpected behavior. More details in other answers.

Comment: Double check my answer, I clarified within the answer that this would be fine for a build server, not for daily development use etc...

Comment: We had a problem with a hotfix of some oldish code. Build server was failing until depth was increased.

Comment: I don't think that is a valid argument to dispute that clone depth 1 is fine for a general build server. Cloning at depth 1 should have nothing to do with your build failing if you are testing the same commit.

Comment: What do you mean by general build server? I think that this is why our builds had issues at depth of 1, from the git user manual: "Merging inside a <<def_shallow_clone,shallow clone>> will work as long
as a merge base is in the recent history.
Otherwise, it will be like merging unrelated histories and may
have to result in huge conflicts.  This limitation may make such
a repository unsuitable to be used in merge based workflows."  (https://github.com/git/git/blame/9cfde9ee8f6dc82365f1e977935960f34108076b/Documentation/user-manual.txt#L2145)

Comment: If you are running `merge` or other git tasks on the build server, then I completely agree that clone depth 1 is not suitable, and will almost surely break. But to build an executable of `HEAD`, clone depth 1 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your build process isn't using GitVersion.  It needs the full history to determine the SemVer

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean? This is not an area that I'm an expert in. What do you mean by GitVersion and SemVer?